# JavaScript function is not triggering

Tags: javascript, html

I have html/kendo ui mobile as follows:

```
<li><a data-action="initContactView" data-click="initContactView">Contacts</a></li>
```

then javascript:

```
function initContactView() {
    alert('before');
    var txtSearch = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: =  "txtSearch='" + txtSearch +"'",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "http://xot-wsdl.compx.net/mobile.asmx/ContactGet",
        dataType: "json",
        success: successContact,
    });
    alert('after');
}
```

the function `successContact` is just putting it all in list view.
My problem is when I take out all the code in JavaScript function the alert works fine, as soon as I put all the other code back, nothing happens when I trigger the button.

What the JavaScript code should do is to connect to my web service and retrieve data.

Any help?

Comment: That would be the syntax errors halting your code execution, such as `data: = 'string'` etc. which is not valid

Comment: ok cool thanx, is there any way I can debug javascript not using alerts?

Comment: Yes, using the [***console***](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have a syntax problem on "data: ="
2. I see you use jQuery, why don't use `$("#searchTextField")` for
   find the field?
3. txtSearch with getElementById will return a DOM element, non the
   value of the field, use this istead:

   `var txtSearch = $("#searchTextField").val();`

EDIT: For debugging you can use FireBug with Mozilla or any other developers tools available in al major browsers.

EDIT 2: In the ajax URL i see a complete URL, please be sure that the url is in the same domain of your web server or you will get a permission denied error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google Chrome you can press Ctrl+Shift+I - Also firefox. Then you can debug your javascript errors by looking for the erros in debug.